# antcall in foreach is not executing loop

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I want to build couple of projects based on no of .composites by using ant scripts.
i added all the taskref tags,lib path every thing in my build.xml file.
i wrote the following piece of code for the same and i am getting the error 
**foreach doesn't support the nested "antcall" element.**

```
<target name="createApplicationDAA">
<foreach param="program">
    <path>
        <fileset dir="${soaProjectName}/Composites" includes="**/*.composite"/>
    </path>
    <antcall target="createDAA"/>
</foreach>
</target>
<target name="createDAA">
..........
....
</target>
```

clearly,
my requirement is to create all DAAs by building all the composites by using foreach or for loop in ant script.
can anybody please let me know,where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` doesn't use nested elements to determine what to run, it takes a `target` attribute:

```
<target name="createApplicationDAA">
  <foreach param="program" target="createDAA">
    <path>
      <fileset dir="${soaProjectName}/Composites" includes="**/*.composite"/>
    </path>
  </foreach>
</target>
<target name="createDAA">
  <echo>${program}</echo>
</target>
```

Alternatively, use `<for>`, which takes a nested `<sequential>`

```
<target name="createApplicationDAA">
  <for param="program">
    <path>
      <fileset dir="${soaProjectName}/Composites" includes="**/*.composite"/>
    </path>
    <sequential>
      <echo>@{program}</echo>
    </sequential>
  </for>
</target>
```